# Dropdown list text in Chrome weirdness

Tags: google-chrome, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a very strange bug that's only present in Google Chrome. It's a drop-down menu that renders the option text with each character replaced by the one that follows it in Unicode. Here's an image:

[image: WTF??]

As you can see, the word "Loan" becomes "Mpbo". The HTML is straightforward:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LoanId must be a number." 
 data-val-required="The LoanId field is required." id="LoanId" name="LoanId" 
 onchange="this.form.submit();" 
 style="display: inline-block; width: auto; font-size: 12px;">
  <option value="">Loan</option>
  <option>1000001947</option>
  <option>1000002123</option>
  <option>1000003227</option>
  <option>1000003396</option>
</select>
```

Custom CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
body {
font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
background-color: #ecf0f5;
color: #646e79;
font-size: 0.875em;
line-height: 1.4;
}
select {
padding: 0.35em 0.75em;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
background: #ecf0f5;
border: 1px solid #ecf0f5;
color: #323640;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
::selection {
background: rgba(100, 110, 121, 0.2);
text-shadow: none;
}
```

I created [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4h6D/) but it works fine there in Chrome, so I really have no idea what this is. The site is done in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Twitter Bootstrap 3.0. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Maybe problem is with character encoding, look at: [meta charset MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) & [@charset - CSS MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the SVG fonts we were using. In my example, I used the Google API for my `@import` source because I couldn't link to the actual font files on the company's server. Once I replaced the URLs to our local files with the URLs directly to Google, then that took care of my problem.